Maximal toral $\iff$ toral and maximal abelian?
Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $\mathfrak g$ be a finite-dimensional Lie-algebra over $K$. Let $\mathfrak h$ be a subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$. Then is it true that [$\mathfrak h$ is maximal toral $\iff$ $\mathfrak h$ is toral and maximal abelian]?
$\mathfrak h$ is said to be toral if and only if for all $H\in\mathfrak h$, the linear map $\operatorname{ad}H:\mathfrak g\to\mathfrak g$ is semisimple. It is known that if the base-field is algebraically closed, then a linear map $\mathfrak g\to\mathfrak g$ is semisimple if and only if it is diagonalizable.
I know that if $K$ is algebraically closed, then [$\mathfrak h$ is toral $\implies$ $\mathfrak h$ is abelian]. So [$\mathfrak h$ is maximal toral $\impliedby$ $\mathfrak h$ is toral and maximal abelian] is true. But how can I prove [$\mathfrak h$ is maximal toral $\implies$ $\mathfrak h$ is toral and maximal abelian]?

$\def\ad{\operatorname{ad}}
\def\lspan{\operatorname{span}}$
The implication is false. Let $E_{ij}$ be the $3 \times 3$ matrix with a $1$ in the $(i,j)$-entry and zeros elsewhere. A counterexample can be found within $\mathfrak{g} = \lspan\{E_{12}, E_{13}, E_{32}\}$, where the Lie bracket is taken to be the matrix commutator. The following is the multiplication table for the basis elements. $$\begin{matrix}
 & E_{12} & E_{13} & E_{32} \\
E_{12} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
E_{13} & 0 & 0 & E_{12} \\
E_{32} & 0 & -E_{12} & 0
\end{matrix}$$
Let $\mathfrak{h} = \lspan\{E_{12}\}$, which is a toral subalgebra according to the multiplication table. $\mathfrak{h}$ is not a maximal abelian subalgebra since $\lspan\{E_{12}, E_{13}\}$ and $\lspan\{E_{12}, E_{32}\}$ are abelian subalgebras. However, we claim that $\mathfrak{h}$ is a maximal toral subalgebra.
Any subalgebra strictly containing $\mathfrak{h}$ must contain a matrix of the form $H = aE_{13} + bE_{32}$ where $a \neq 0$ or $b \neq 0$. For such an element, $\ad_{H}$ is not semisimple. Consider $\mathfrak{h}$, which is $\ad_{H}$-invariant. Any complement of $\mathfrak{h}$ must have two linearly independent vectors with "pivots" on $E_{13}$ and $E_{32}$, and so we may find a basis of the complement consisting of matrices of the form $$X = c E_{12} + E_{13}, Y = d E_{12} + E_{32}$$ where $c, d \in K$. At least one of $$\ad_{H}(X) = [H, X] = -bE_{12}$$ $$\ad_{H}(Y) = [H, Y] = aE_{12}$$ is nonzero and not in $\lspan\{X, Y\}$.
